# Wait for all threads in a pool to complete their work

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to replace in an adapted code from internet, a thread pooling class, named `ThreadPool`:

> ```
> void ThreadPool::Wait()
> {
>   // we're done waiting once all threads are waiting
>   while (m_threads_waiting != m_threads.size())
>   {
>       ;
>   }
> }
> ```

where `m_threads_waiting` is defined as:

> ```
> std::atomic<size_t> m_threads_waiting{ 0 };
> ```

and `m_threads` is defined as:

> ```
> std::vector<std::thread> m_threads;
> ```

The replacing code is:

```
void ThreadPool::Wait()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{ m_wait_mutex };
    m_threads_done.wait(lock, [&]()
                                {
                                    return m_threads_waiting != m_threads.size();
                                });
    lock.unlock();
}
```

where `m_wait_mutex` is defined as:

```
std::mutex m_wait_mutex;
```

and `m_threads_done` is defined as:

```
std::condition_variable m_threads_done;
```

The code is self-explanatory: the `Wait()` method should "wait" until all threads are done. And this method is called on main thread. Please tell me the the replaced code is correct and it is better than the old one.

I put here the header of the source code:

```
class ThreadPool
{
public:
    ThreadPool();
    ThreadPool(const ThreadPool& rhs) = delete;
    ThreadPool& operator=(const ThreadPool& rhs) = delete;
    ThreadPool(ThreadPool&& rhs) = default;
    ThreadPool& operator=(ThreadPool&& rhs) = default;
    ~ThreadPool();
    template<typename Func, typename... Args>
    auto Add(Func&& func, Args&&... args) -> std::future<typename std::result_of<Func(Args...)>::type>;
    size_t GetWaitingJobs() const;
    void Clear();
    void Pause(const bool& state);
    // blocks calling thread until job queue is empty
    void Wait();
    bool IsPaused() const { return m_paused; }
    bool IsTerminate() const { return m_terminate; }
    bool IsJobsEmpty() const { return m_jobs.empty(); }

private:
    using Job = std::function<void()>;
    // variables
    std::queue<Job> m_jobs;
    std::mutex m_wait_mutex;
    mutable std::mutex m_jobs_mutex;
    std::condition_variable m_threads_done;
    std::condition_variable m_jobs_available;   // notification variable for waiting threads
    std::vector<std::thread> m_threads;
    std::atomic<size_t> m_threads_waiting{ 0 };
    std::atomic<bool> m_terminate{ false };
    std::atomic<bool> m_paused{ false };
    // methods
    static void ThreadTask(ThreadPool* pPool);  // function each thread performs
};
```

and the implementation:

```
ThreadPool::ThreadPool()
{
    const size_t threadCount = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();

    m_threads.reserve(threadCount);
    std::generate_n(
                    std::back_inserter(m_threads), 
                    threadCount, 
                    [this]()
                    {
                        return std::thread{ ThreadPool::ThreadTask, this };
                    });
}

ThreadPool::~ThreadPool()
{
    Clear();

    m_terminate.store(true);
    m_jobs_available.notify_all();

    for (auto& t : m_threads)
    {
        if (t.joinable())
            t.join();
    }
}

size_t ThreadPool::GetWaitingJobs() const
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{ m_jobs_mutex };

    return m_jobs.size();
}

void ThreadPool::Clear()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{ m_jobs_mutex };

    while (! m_jobs.empty())
        m_jobs.pop();
}

void ThreadPool::Pause(const bool& state)
{
    m_paused = state;

    if (! m_paused)
        m_jobs_available.notify_all();
}
#include <iostream>
void ThreadPool::Wait()
{
    // we're done waiting once all threads are waiting
/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    while (m_threads_waiting != m_threads.size());
/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    std::cout << "\nbefore lock\n";
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{ m_wait_mutex };
    std::cout << "\nafter lock\n";
    m_threads_done.wait(lock, [&, this]()
                            {
                                return m_threads_waiting <= m_threads.size();
                            });
    lock.unlock();
///*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    std::cout << "\nafter un-lock\n";
}
// function each thread performs
void ThreadPool::ThreadTask(ThreadPool* pPool)
{
    // loop until we break (to keep thread alive)
    while (true)
    {
        if (pPool->m_terminate)
            break;

        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{ pPool->m_jobs_mutex };

        // if there are no more jobs, or we're paused, go into waiting mode
        if (pPool->m_jobs.empty() || pPool->m_paused)
        {
            ++pPool->m_threads_waiting;

            pPool->m_jobs_available.wait(lock, [&]()
                                            {
                                                return pPool->IsTerminate() ||
                                                    ! (pPool->IsJobsEmpty() || pPool->IsPaused());
                                            });

            --pPool->m_threads_waiting;
        }

        if (pPool->m_terminate)
            break;

        auto job = std::move(pPool->m_jobs.front());
        pPool->m_jobs.pop();
        lock.unlock();
        job();
    }
}
```

The point is `ThreadPool::Wait()` method.

Comment: The replaced code is correct and it is better than the old one.

Comment: Thank you @BlameTheBits, I have noticed that `return m_threads_waiting != m_threads.size();` could not be proper, sometime the main thread is blocking. However, `return m_threads_waiting <= m_threads.size();` seem to work ok.

Comment: I learned again that humor is hard to transport and spot in comments. I was just following your 'instruction' telling you that everything's fine. Sorry for that. But on first glance it actually looks fine (not sure if your commented modification is needed btw - if you execute `Wait` from the main thread, how can it still be blocking?). But I'm not good with C++ threads so I cannot guarantee you anything. One thing I am wondering is how `m_threads_waiting` is updated.

Comment: Btw the 'is it even working correctly' makes it out of scope for this website. You should make sure of that first (maybe with the help of SO if needed)

Comment: So, you are joking when you said that `The replaced code is correct and it is better than the old one` ? I have updated my original post.

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community where we review code that is known to be working as expected to the best of your knowledge. If you don't know if the code is working or not, then it is not ready for code review on this site. To do a good review of the code we need to see the entire definition of the class `ThreadPool`. Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) so that you can improve the question.

Comment: Ok, I will add the ThreadPool code source. I will come back then.

Comment: @pacmaninbw I added the source code. I am not completely get it why `return m_threads_waiting != m_threads.size();` is block the main thread and `return m_threads_waiting <= m_threads.size();` do not, by simply calling `ThreadPool pool;` and `pool.Wait();` in the main thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Missing definitions

The header needs quite a few standard library types:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <functional>
#include <future>
#include <mutex>
#include <queue>
#include <thread>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

using std::size_t;
```

I wouldn't recommend polluting the global namespace like that in the header, though - that's quite rude to the client code.  Instead, write `std::size_t` in full.

---

Using `std::jthread` instead of `std::thread` would let us remove the `join()` loop from the destructor.

---

We can simplify emptying the queue.  Instead of this loop:

> ```
> while (! m_jobs.empty())
>     m_jobs.pop();
> ```

we can simply assign an empty queue:

```
m_jobs = {};
```

---

`ThreadPool::Wait()` shouldn't be printing to the output stream - that will likely corrupt the program output.  If we need some diagnostics, use `std::clog` instead.  But really, just remove that because it will annoy users.

The lambda passed to `wait()` doesn't need a default capture (`[&, this]`).  Reduce it to just `[this]` so that it's clearer to readers.

---

`ThreadPool::ThreadTask()` is given a pointer; I think that would be clearer if it were a reference (construct the thread with `std::ref(*this)` as argument).

`while (true)` can be `while (!pPool->m_terminate)`.  Consider using a `std::stop_token` rather than separately testing `m_terminate`.

---

All our atomic accesses use the default, strongest memory order, `std::memory_order_seq_cst`.  Consider whether this is always appropriate; I believe we can use weaker ordering in most places.